# Pictures in SQL DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, image, sql-server-2008

how big (binary(xy)) should I make my table column in SQL database if I want to store there pictures taken by camera - that means variable size up to.. I don't know.. 7MB? But if I should rather limit the size up to 2MB or something, I would. Whats your opinion?

**EDIT**

Or where else should I store them? I am building a web gallery using asp.net mvc.

Comment: What database server are you running?

Comment: Currently VS2008. I intend to use SQL Server 2008 Express.

Comment: I know this isn't what you asked about but I would feel bad if I didn't mention this. It's a very subjective topic but I find storing images in the database horrible. The only advantage imho is that you can backup and move the data in the db and images together but other then that I feel it overcomplicates things. You need custom code for starring and retrieving, it's hard to manually make an alteration, often db space is expensive etc... you might have a good reason to want this but give it some thought.

Comment: totally agree, let the filesystem/operationsystem handle the files, not the sql database. Only save the filename in the database so you can generate the path to it later on. A varchar for the filename should do it.

Comment: Well my main reason is that I don't really know where else to store them. I am quite new at this. Plus I find the DB code manipulation easy.

Comment: The FILESTREAM documentation gives a good comparison of options: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're talking about is a `varbinary` column. Of course, if you make `varbinary` greater than 8000, it immediately converts it into a `varbinary(max)` column, meaning it can store up to 2GB. This has to do with how SQL Server stores rows (8k per page).

Therefore, each row stores the column as a pointer to the bits, anyway. So, what I would do, if I were me, would be to store the images on the file system, and store the location of those files inside the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store images in SQL Server then use the varbinary(max) column type. It permits up to 2Gb (if I recall).

Also, as you are using SQL Server 2008 (I don't know about the express edition tho') you could use the new [filestream](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid87_gci1356593,00.html) data type.

Of course the big advantage of storing this in the database is that you only have one thing to back up and you don't have issues with the file system and database getting out of sync. The new filestream type is an interesting development because it can help alleviate these problems.

The disadvantage of storing this data in the database is that you put additional strain on the database, especially if the bandwidth between your database and webserver is already strained.

Comment: While this FILESTREAM is really cool, it plays havoc with things like backups and specially restore: you'll never get back to a specific point in time if you use that.

Comment: So, it turns out to be more of a hindrance than a help? However, just storing the files in the file system manually has issues with data sync'ing especially with backup/restore too.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already stated in comments (which BTW you guys should have been answers despite the pendantic police) you really have to have some killer reason to store images in the database.  Otherwise just place them in the file system.

Especially this is true in the case where the images are delivered from a web server.  The web server is way more effecient at delivering images from the file system than your code will be extracting them from a database.